# Error- An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions when trying to send email

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, smtp

I'm trying to send an email from a asp.net website but am seeing this error:

> {"An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions xx.xxx.xx.xxx:587"}

The same code, same SMTP credentials is used in another console application that is successfully sending emails, but the asp.net application gives me the above error.

I'm running both the console application and website on my local machine.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you check whether you have port 587 open in windows firewall for socket communication?

Comment: Do you have `smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;` in your code ?

Comment: Yes EnableSsl is true and the other console application is also using port 587 to send email..and is successfully sending emails...and both are running on my machine

Comment: Are you running both of them at the same time?

Comment: No both are not executed on same time